# WOE transformation for validation data

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm doing logistic regression & XGBoost and converted all variable into `WOE`'s. 
This was done for the training data set. 
Now I would like to validate my model on my validation & out-of-sample test data. 
`WOE` were produced by using the `Hmisc::CUT2` function and then apply `InformationValue::WOE`

```
data.work$MAILING_DAYS <- cut2(training$MAILING_DAYS, g=20, cuts=c(16,23,27))

data.work.woe$MAILING_DAYS <-  WOE(data.work$MAILING_DAYS,
                                   data.work$SUCCESS,
                                   valueOfGood=1)
```

Possible Information would be:

```
 WOETable(data.work$MAILING_DAYS,
     data.work$SUCCESS,
     valueOfGood=1)
      CAT GOODS  BADS TOTAL      PCT_G     PCT_B         WOE          IV
1 [ 0,16)  4827 89389 94216 0.58844325 0.4983581  0.16616157 0.014968688
2 [16,23)  1750 41383 43133 0.21333658 0.2307169 -0.07832034 0.001361233
3 [23,27)   987 27323 28310 0.12032183 0.1523301 -0.23588003 0.007550120
4 [27,30]   639 21272 21911 0.07789833 0.1185948 -0.42030843 0.017105085

levels(data.work$MAILING_DAYS)
[1] "[ 0,16)" "[16,23)" "[23,27)" "[27,30]"
```

I tried something like that:

```
WOE <- data.frame(NAME=character(), 
                  COND=character(),
                  VALUE=integer(),
                  WOE =integer(),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
a = names(data.work)
WOE.CAT <- c()
WOE.WOE <- c()
k <- 1

for (i in c(4:4)){
  temp.var <- a[i]
  WOE.CAT <- WOETable(data.work[, temp.var], data.work$SUCCESS, valueOfGood = 1)$CAT
  WOE.WOE <- WOETable(data.work[, temp.var], data.work$SUCCESS, valueOfGood = 1)$WOE
  for (j in c(2:length(WOE.CAT))){
    if (as.integer(gregexpr(pattern=",", WOE.CAT[j]) == -1)){ 
      WOE[k,"NAME"]  <- temp.var
      WOE[k,"COND"]  <- "<"
      WOE[k,"VALUE"] <- as.numeric(WOE.CAT[j+1])
      WOE[k, "WOE"]  <- WOE.WOE[j]
      k <- k + 1     
    } else if (as.integer(gregexpr(pattern=",", WOE.CAT[j]) != -1)){ 
      if (j < (length(WOE.CAT)-1)){
        WOE[k,"NAME"]  <- temp.var
        WOE[k,"COND"]  <- "<"
        WOE[k,"VALUE"] <- as.numeric(substr(WOE.CAT[j], (as.integer(gregexpr(pattern=",", WOE.CAT[j]))+1), (nchar(WOE.CAT[j])-1)))
        WOE[k, "WOE"]  <- WOE.WOE[j]
        k <- k + 1
      } else if(j == (length(WOE.CAT)-1)){
        WOE[k,"NAME"]  <- temp.var
        WOE[k,"COND"]  <- ">="
        WOE[k,"VALUE"] <- as.numeric(substr(WOE.CAT[j], 2, (as.integer(gregexpr(pattern=",", WOE.CAT[j]))-1)))
        WOE[k, "WOE"]  <- WOE.WOE[j]
        k <- k + 1
      } 
    } else if (WOE.CAT[j] == "missing"){
      WOE[k,"NAME"]  <- temp.var
      WOE[k,"COND"]  <- "=="
      WOE[k,"VALUE"] <- NA
      WOE[k, "WOE"]  <- WOE.WOE[j]
      k <- k + 1
    }
  }
}
```

There should be a way to transform WOE from training data to validation data, is there?

The stupid way would be `if else if` ... but I have over 250 characteristics, so this would take a bunch of time!

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have a solution,

using package: scorecard is helpful. In my case i used the determined breaks breaks_list in scorecard::woebin und create the data with scorecard::woebin_ply